# Updating the existing model with Model Generator

Tags: yii

I generate model with Model Generator and then (afterward) add a new table and new foreign keys relations.

Is it possible to update the existing model with model generator?

Or do I need to edit the code manually when I add a new table?

Comment: generate new it will automatically overwrite the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [gii-template-collection](https://github.com/schmunk42/gii-template-collection) and it's **FullModel** template.

It generates by default two classes for your models, `BaseModel` and `Model`. Best-practice for me is to add my custom functions, behaviors, scopes, etc... to `Model` and leave `BaseModel` untouched.

If you have changes in your database schema, just re-generate the `BaseModel` class.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't edit the existing model with Gii tool. You will have to either manually update the model or generate a new one.